# Is there any technical term for a type of reading that focuses on minor characters in a literary work?

Tags: terminology

Is there any technical term for a type of reading that focuses on minor characters in a literary work? For example, a type of reading that focuses on the character of Polonius in William Shakespeare's *Hamlet* or on the character of Jordan Baker from *The Great Gatsby*.

Answer (score -1):

This would probably be what is called a **[parallel novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_novel)**. Common examples include *Wide Sargasso Sea*, *Rosencrantz and Guildenstern Are Dead*, and *Grendel*. To quote wikipedia:

> These stories further the works of already well-known novels by focusing on a minor character and making them the major character

so it seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I like this answer, but I'm not sure if this is what the author of the question is looking for? It almost sounds like they're asking if there is a name for the process of rereading a story but focusing on the characters who aren't central to the plot.

Comment: @Lockjaw Ah, I see what you mean. I'll look for that term, I suppose, but I'm not entirely sure it exists =)

Comment: *R&G are Dead* isn't a novel.